# Eclipse takes ages to display breakpoint when running tomcat

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, tomcat5.5

When tomcat hits a breakpoint in Eclipse, the execution thread stops, but the breakpoint takes absolutely ages to appear in Eclipse. The same is true if I try to inspect a variable; the first time takes about 2 minutes. After that, the debug session is fine.

What with that and the CONSTANT need to keep re-publishing to tomcat every time I change something, it's driving me nuts.

Does anybody have any ideas why it's so slow?

Also, how can I stop tomcat restarting the webapp every time I try to change something during a debug session? I am sure it never used to do that...

Eclipse is  3.3.1.1 with J2EE Standard Tools and Web Standard Tools. Tomcat is 5.5

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open server in server view and disable automatic publishing.

How much memory your computer have? May be swapping is the reason behind slow debugging. I am having much better experience since my computer has 2Gb of memory instead of 1Gb. Also, check your expession view. A lot of expressions can slow eclipse down.